# When to add Sequential Primary key ? before or after insertion?

Tags: oracle

I have a table with Primary key which takes a sequential value by a **trigger**.

what is the best time to add that key ?

**before** or **after** insert?

Comment: it may depends on other conditions but almost it's better to be in **before** trigger, however you can do it in a after trigger also then update it but it's not recommended

Comment: Sorry, that's wrong. AFTER triggers cannot modify the value of any columns in the triggering table. You would only use a BEFORE trigger for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do the trigger before insert, so the primary key value can be retrieved from a sequence prior to inserting the row.  This allows table constraints to be satisfied for a primary key (not null and unique).

Comment: if I used **before** trigger and got a new value from the sequence before insertion, but the final transaction was rolled back,
then I will lose a sequential value from the sequence.
I don't want that to happened.

Comment: Sequences aren't guaranteed to not have gaps in the sequence because of situations you just described.  Is there a reason you don't want this to happen?  Primary keys just have to be unique not sequential.

Comment: @Nosairat: there is absolutely no way to prevent the "sequential values lost during a rollback" situation. Can't do it. Get over it. Values from a sequence are just numbers. Say it again - They're Just Numbers. They have no meaning. They have no "spirit" or "soul" or whatever. They're Just Numbers. They don't "die" because the transaction gets rolled back. They're not alive. They're Just Numbers. Breathe in - breathe out - move on.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a record in a table with a primary key, you will have to provide a unique key value right away.